# sense of the preposion "of" in the sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

Given:

> "Second  to  KL  in  size  are  the  historic  trading  cities  of  Melaka  and  Penang,  with  buildings dating  back  hundreds  of  years  and  wonderful  unspoilt  districts  where  visitors  can  breathe  in  the romance of the past."

My teacher says Melaka and Penang are the historic cities. But I am confused with using the phrase "the historic trading cities of Melaka and Penang".
I think it means there are historic  trading cities in Malaka and Penang. Melaka and Penang may not be historic trading cities according to the textual clue.

So, are Malaka and Penang the historic trading cities and the second biggest cities according to the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Both interpretations are plausible.

> *Last summer, I visited the historic cities of Italy and Greece*.

I would interpret this to mean that the speaker visited cities such as Florence, Venice, and Athens.

> *Last summer, I visited the historic cities of Vienna and Salzburg*.

This sentence lists two historic cities that the speaker visited.

So, grammatically, the structure you ask about (*the cities of X and Y*) could refer to cities *inside* X and Y, or to the cities themselves. There’s even a third possibility:

> *Last summer, I visited the cities of Trinidad and Tobago*.

(Since Trinidad and Tobago is the name of a single country, that sentence is talking about visiting cities inside one country, not two.)

Therefore, there’s really know way to tell what your sentence means – not without more context. However, my initial assumption would be that Melaka and Penang are the names of two cities.

One clue to deciphering the intended meaning would be the inclusion or exclusion of the definite article, and the choice of prepositions. One could argue that:

> *Last summer, I visited the historic cities of Italy and Greece*.

might imply that I visited **all** historic cities in those two countries. If I only visited three cities, it might be more accurate to say:

> *Last summer, I visited historic cities **in** Italy and Greece*.

However, I don’t think the inclusion of the definite article is governed that inflexibly, so there is some inherent ambiguity in the statement – particularly when you are unfamiliar with the proper nouns, and don’t know if they are the name of a city, county, province, or nation.